# how to display Input Vale after clcik On form in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Enter Your Data!</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeVal() 
{ 
document.getElementById("textfield2").value="abc";   
} 

</script>



<BODY>
    <form method="GET" action='index.jsp' name="good">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="textfield2" />
        <input type="text" name="done" value='<%=request.getAttribute("k")%>' />
        <% String k=request.getParameter("done");

 request.setAttribute("k",k);
%>

    </form>



</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is my simple index.jsp file code am unable to display text after Button click please Help me how i ll do this after Button click Text disappointing of iN put value

Comment: if you are talking about JS changeVal() method, I would say it never get invoked!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you want to display submitted value.
Try to change

```
<input type="text" name="done" value='<%=request.getAttribute("k")%>' />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="done" value='<%=request.getParameter("done")%>' />
```

But it's better not to do any logic in jsp. Try to move all logic into servlet or any other controller.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call the `changeVal()` somewhere in your code, probably in onload of the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<%
    String paramValue = request.getParameter("submit");
    paramValue = (paramValue==null)?"":paramValue;
%>

var buttonValue = <%=paramValue%>;

function changeVal() 
{ 
    if(buttonValue!="")
    {
        document.getElementById("textfield2").value = buttonValue;
    }
} 

function formSubmit()
{
    //set the value need to be changed
    document.getElementById("textfield2").value="abc";
    document.getElementById("good").submit();
}

</script>

<BODY onload="changeVal()">
    <form method="GET" action='index.jsp' id="good" name="good">

        <input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" name="submit" value="submit" id="textfield2" /> 
        <input type="text" name="done" value='<%=request.getAttribute("k")%>' />

        <% 
         String k=request.getParameter("done");
         request.setAttribute("k",k);
        %>

    </form>
</BODY>
```